# Proving that this is a topological property

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set, so I want to prove that having the discrete topology is a topological property, but I am not sure how to do this since I know that every set can be made always a topological space with the discrete and indiscrete topology, so I don't know what to do here.

Can someone help me to prove this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Topological property:
```

Let $X$ be a topological space then a topological invariant or a topological property $P$ is a property of topological spaces such that if $X$ have it and $X \simeq Y$ then so does $Y$.

> **My answer**:

We take $Z \subset Y$ then we write $f(f^{-1}(Z))=Z$ so since $X$ has the discrete topology $f^{-1}(Z)$ is open and since $f^{-1}$ is continuous $f(f^{-1}(Z))$ is open, therefore $Y$ has the discrete topology.

Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by topological property??

Comment: First of all, remember what the *definition* of the term "topological property" is.

Comment: Ok, just a second and I post it :)

Comment: Ready :) I've edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show: If any subset of $X$ is open and $f: X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then any subset of $Y$ is open.

I will just give you the following hint: For any $Z \subset Y$, we have $f(f^{-1}(Z))=Z$.

Comment: Ok let me try that, but if I have questions can I let you know?

Comment: I've edited my post :), what do you think?

Comment: Yes, this is all fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) for your help I will let my post like that so more could be beneficent of the proof :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Your answer: "We take $Z \subset Y$ then we write $f(f^{-1}(Z))=Z$ so since $X$ has the discrete topology $f^{-1}(Z)$ is open and since $f^{-1}$ is continuous $f(f^{-1}(Z))$ is open, therefore $Y$ has the discrete topology", contains all the necessary ingredients for a correct proof, but is much to terse. I had to read it several times until I understood what you wanted to say. I'd put it as follows:

Assume that $X$ has the discrete topology, and let $f:\>X\to Y$ be a homeomorphism. Consider an arbitrary subset $Z\subset Y$. As $\hat Z:=f^{-1}(Z)\subset X$ is open and $f^{-1}$ is continuous it follows that $Z=f(\hat Z)$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: Ok, this is an alternative proof :), so the one that I posted , is it wrong?

Comment: jajaj what do you mean by tersely?

Comment: Then what do you suggest to improve it ?

Comment: I dont understand this answer. Your "proof" is just a reformulation of the proof by the OP...

Comment: @MooS: I wrote this Edit of my previous answer because the OP (user162343) asked for suggestions in a comment.